# Using data from one DataTable to get results for another

Tags: c#, datatables

I currently have a stored procedure that exports to a DataTable (`dt`). The data provided shows the value each customer had, on average, for each month. The data must show their values, if they have a value to show.

Here is the SQL for my stored procedure (dynamic Pivot Table):

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[stpMonthlyAvg]
--Parameters
AS
Begin

Begin Tran T1;

    Begin Try

        DECLARE @Dates NVARCHAR(MAX);

        SELECT @Dates = CONCAT(@Dates + ', ', QUOTENAME(BalMonth))
        FROM vAvgMonBal
        GROUP BY BalMonth
        ORDER BY BalMonth;

        DECLARE @DynSQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
                @months NVARCHAR(255);

        SET @months = 'CONCAT( CONVERT(nvarchar(15), YEAR(BalDate)) , IIF(LEN(MONTH(BalDate)) > 1, CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate)), ''0'' + CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate))))'
        SET @DynSQL = 'SELECT *
                       FROM
                           (SELECT 
                                a1.IDNbr, 
                                a2.CustName, ' + @months + ' AS BalMonth,
                                AVG(a1.Balance) as Balance
                            FROM tblID a1 
                            INNER JOIN tblCust a2 ON (a1.IDNbr = a2.IDNbr)
                            WHERE a2.CustType != ''Inactive'' AND a2.CustType IS NOT NULL AND a1.Balance != 0 
                            GROUP BY 
                                a1.IDNbr, a2.CustName, ' + @months +') as d1
        PIVOT (
            AVG(Balance)
            FOR BalMonth IN (' + @Dates + ')
        ) piv';

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSQL

    Commit Tran T1;

End Try

Begin Catch

    RollBack Tran T1;
End Catch

End
```

Here's an example of the table I currently have-- with test data:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | CustName | 201501 | 201502 | 201503 | 201504 | ..|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 32 | CustOne  | 100.00 | 200.00 | 400.00 | 700.00 | ..|
| 56 | CustTwo  | 350.00 | 375.00 | 400.00 | 500.00 | ..|
| 89 | CustThree| 222.22 | 333.33 | 444.44 | 555.55 | ..|
| .. | ...      |   ..   |   ..   |   ..   |   ..   | ..|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm needing to find the percent difference between each month with the previous month, per customer, and add that to its own DataTable(`fDt`).

Here is what I'm needing (values in the rows are percentages):

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | CustName | PerDiff02 | PerDiff03 | PerDiff04 | ..|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 32 | CustOne  |     0     |     100   |     200   | ..|
| 56 | CustTwo  |   93.33   |    93.75  |    80.00  | ..|
| 89 | CustThree|   66.66   |    75.00  |    80.00  | ..|
| .. | ...      |   ....    |    ....   |    ....   | ..|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

I currently have the data being added to `fDt` , though it's calculating per column, rather than per row (I think).

Meaning my data output looks like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | CustName | PerDiff02 | PerDiff03 | PerDiff04 | ..|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 32 | CustOne  |     0     |    100    |    200    | ..|
| 56 | CustTwo  |     0     |    100    |    200    | ..|
| 89 | CustThree|     0     |    100    |    200    | ..|
| .. | ...      |   ....    |   ....    |   ....    | ..|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

As it's assigning the entire column the result of one calculation.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
        Uni.fileExport Export = new Uni.fileExport();
        string conStr = "Data Source=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataSource"] + "Initial Catalog=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InitialCatalog"] + "Integrated Security=True;";

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt = Export.sqlToDTMonthlyAvg(conStr, stp);
        var fDt = new DataTable();

        int i;
        int fieldCount = dt.Columns.Count;
        int finalSize = (fieldCount) * 2;
        string[] finalCol = new string[finalSize];
        string[] colHeaders = new string[fieldCount];

        for (i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
        {
            colHeaders[i] = dt.Columns[i].ToString();
        }

        fDt.Columns.Add(colHeaders[0]);
        fDt.Columns.Add(colHeaders[1]);



        for (i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            fDt.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i][0], dt.Rows[i][1]);
        }


        /* 
         * This section is meant to try and get the percent difference from dt 
         * to fDt. Looking into doing this from the SQL data base rather than from the code
         * in order to save processing at runTime. The main concern being the stored procedure
         * taking longer than a couple minutes. 
         */

        // Gets the column headers for dataTable fDt
        for (i = 2; i <= (dt.Columns.Count - 2); i++)
        {
            string colName = "PerDiff" + dt.Columns[i + 1];
            fDt.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(decimal));
        }

        for (i = 2; i <= (dt.Columns.Count - 2); i++)
        {
            var month1 = dt.Columns[i];
            var month2 = dt.Columns[i + 1];
            fDt.Columns[i].Expression = $"({month1} / {month2}) * 100";

        }
```

**Question:** How can I get the percent differences of the columns of `dt` to `fDt`? I'm needing the percentages based off the previous month.

(PerDiff starts at `PerDiff02` due to the fact that there is nothing before `201501` to be compared.)

If anything is unclear, please let me know and I will try my best to clarify! I'm still a bit new to C#, especially `datatables`.

I attempted to try this in SQL, however I'm still very much a novice with SQL as well and figured this would be easier to achieve via C#. Once I get it working, then optimization will be considered.

If there are any downvotes, I ask that you explain why you are downvoting so that I may correct it!

Comment: [Database Normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/)

Comment: @NewContributor , Thanks for the resource! Could you explain how this applies to what I have? Reading through the information, I'm not sure how to apply this to what I have.

Comment: This would be easier to do in SQL, can you post your stored procedure here?

Comment: @ChinaSyndrome , I've added my stored procedure to the post!

Comment: @New is right; any time you have tables with columns like Datum1, Datum2, ... you need to change that to a single Datum column and a column for discriminator (month, period, whatever). SQL is row-oriented; all aggregate functions and grouping is by row, not by column. You have no idea what a can of hurt you're opening by trying to split data across columns. I know this stuff is not obvious, but you have got to normalize your data.

Comment: @DourHighArch , Thank you for your input! I believe my data _is_ normalized within my database. Though, creating a Pivot Table with my data may make it seem (or cause it to be) non-normalized(?). Would you have any suggestions on how to go about it?

Comment: `Month1`, `Month2` is not normalized, you need to fix that before doing anything else. Requiring pivots or cursors are symptoms of denormalized data, do not use them unless they are absolutely necessary, and they rarely are. Normalization is too large a topic for a Stack Overflow answer, start with the site @New mentioned. The further you go without normalizing your data the more problems you are going to have.

Comment: @DourHighArch , I must still be confused on how my data isn't normalized. I've corrected my tables to show how my data is represented (I over looked it when I had originally typed out the question)

Answer (score 1):

ok this is what I did 2 years ago for something similar

On your inner select add the diffs for place holders

```
SELECT 
                                a1.IDNbr, 
                                a2.CustName, ' + @months + ' AS BalMonth,
                                AVG(a1.Balance) as Balance,
0 as Diff1,0 as Diff2,0 as Diff3
```

before EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSQL   add

```
DECLARE @DataProcess TABLE // Table variable to hold everything
    (
        NewTableID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        ,  Id INT
        , CustName NVARCHAR(256)
        , Month1 NVARCHAR(260)
        , Month2 NVARCHAR(260)
        , Month3 NVARCHAR(260)
        , Month4 NVARCHAR(260)
        ,Diff1 INT
        ,Diff2 INT
        ,Diff3 INT
    )




    INSERT INTO @DataProcess EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSQL // fill in the data 

Now declare values and loop 
DECLARE @Count INT, @Counter INT, @Id INT,@Month1  NVARCHAR(260),@Month1  NVARCHAR(260),@Month3  NVARCHAR(260),@Month4  NVARCHAR(260)

SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM @DataProcess d
    SET @Counter = 1

BEGIN
        SELECT @Id = ID,(260),@Month1 =  Month1,@Month2=Month1 ,@Month3=Month3 ,@Month4 =Month3    FROM @DataProcess m WHERE NewTableID  = Counter

        m.Diff1 =@Month2 - @Month1;
        m.Diff2 =@Month3 - @Month2
         m.Diff2 =@Month4 - @Month3

        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
 END
```

This should fill it all in for you and not break anythign else using the sp

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would this be able to be applied to dynamic SQL?

Comment: it might be but I am not that good with pivot and unpivot

Comment: Would be able to edit your code posted to show me how I should implement it into my current stored procedure? As of right now, I'm unsure how to apply this to my code

Answer (score 1):

Per request here is what I would do entirely in the stored procedure

```
Begin Tran T1;

    Begin Try

        DECLARE @Dates NVARCHAR(MAX);

        SELECT @Dates = CONCAT(@Dates + ', ', QUOTENAME(BalMonth))
        FROM vAvgMonBal
        GROUP BY BalMonth
        ORDER BY BalMonth;

        DECLARE @DynSQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
                @months NVARCHAR(255);

        SET @months = 'CONCAT( CONVERT(nvarchar(15), YEAR(BalDate)) , IIF(LEN(MONTH(BalDate)) > 1, CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate)), ''0'' + CONVERT(nvarchar(15), MONTH(BalDate))))'
        SET @DynSQL = 'SELECT *
                       FROM
                           (SELECT 
                                a1.IDNbr, 
                                a2.CustName, ' + @months + ' AS BalMonth,
                                AVG(a1.Balance) as Balance,
                0 as Diff1,0 as Diff2,0 as Diff3
                            FROM tblID a1 
                            INNER JOIN tblCust a2 ON (a1.IDNbr = a2.IDNbr)
                            WHERE a2.CustType != ''Inactive'' AND a2.CustType IS NOT NULL AND a1.Balance != 0 
                            GROUP BY 
                                a1.IDNbr, a2.CustName, ' + @month +') as d1
        PIVOT (
            AVG(Balance)
            FOR BalMonth IN (' + @Dates + ')
        ) piv';

        DECLARE @DataProcess TABLE // Table variable to hold everything
    (
        NewTableID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        ,  Id INT
        , CustName NVARCHAR(256)
        , Month1 NVARCHAR(260)
        , Month2 NVARCHAR(260)
        , Month3 NVARCHAR(260)
        , Month4 NVARCHAR(260)
        ,Diff1 INT
        ,Diff2 INT
        ,Diff3 INT
    )




    INSERT INTO @DataProcess EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSQL // fill in the data 
Now declare values and loop 
DECLARE @Count INT, @Counter INT, @Id INT,@Month1  NVARCHAR(260),@Month1  NVARCHAR(260),@Month3  NVARCHAR(260),@Month4  NVARCHAR(260)

SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM @DataProcess d
    SET @Counter = 1

BEGIN
        SELECT @Id = ID,(260),@Month1 =  Month1,@Month2=Month1 ,@Month3=Month3 ,@Month4 =Month3    FROM @DataProcess m WHERE NewTableID  = Counter

        m.Diff1 =@Month2 - @Month1;
        m.Diff2 =@Month3 - @Month2
         m.Diff2 =@Month4 - @Month3

        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
 END    

select * from @DataProcess // this reads all the data in the Temp Table and this is what fills your data table in .NEt
    Commit Tran T1;

End Try

Begin Catch

    RollBack Tran T1;
End Catch

End
```

Comment: Thanks for addition help! However, there's syntax errors I'm unable to solve. The like `m.Diff1 = @Month2 - @Month1;` is giving a syntax error at `m`. (I'm still pretty new with SQL.)